# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\cdot e^{-x} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm having trouble integrating the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\cdot e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor of $x$.

Can you help please?

Comment: what is [x] mean?

Comment: @AmruthA The greatest integer that is less or equal $\;x$

Comment: is the answer =1

Comment: Not according to my textbook.

Comment: Is it $\frac{e-1}{e+1}$?

Answer (score 8):

This could work if I didn't make some mistake

$$\int_0^\infty (-1)^{[x]}e^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}(-1)^ne^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(-e^{-n-1}+e^{-n}\right)=$$

$$=-\frac1e\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-e^{-1})^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-e^{-1}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac1e\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-e^{-1}\right)^n=$$

$$\frac{e-1}e\cdot\frac1{1+e^{-1}}=\frac{e-1}{e+1}$$

Comment: I think the idea is correct. However, I am not sure about the final result. Because, in the second line, if you expand the summations, you would have -1 as one of the terms. But, I think it should be 1. Please let me know if I am wrong

Comment: @Med I very much appreciate your input. Certainly I forgot the minus sign there and it renders a different solution. I shall correct now.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

First try to calculate $$A_n = \int_{n}^{n+1} (-1)^{[x]} e^{-x} dx$$
where $n$ is an integer.

Then your final result is $A_0 + A_1 + \dots$

Comment: I've actually done that, but got stuck after creating the summation of these integrals (and calculating the integral)

Comment: @ChenMordechay Can you show me how far you got? For example, what is $A_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^N (-1)^{[x]}e^{-x}dx&=\int_0^1 e^{-x}dx-\int_1^2 e^{-x}dx+\cdots\\
&=-e^{-1}+1+e^{-2}-e^{-1}-e^{-3}+e^{-2}+\cdots\\
&=1-2e^{-1}+2e^{-2}-2e^{-3}+\cdots\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$
Then, you can pass the result to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in the interval [2k, 2k+1] the integral will be $ \int _{2k} ^{2k+1} e^{-x} dx$, while in [2k+1, 2k+2] it will be $ -\int _{2k+1} ^{2k+2} e^{-x} dx$.
Thus your integral can be written as  $ \sum _{k=0} ^\infty [\int _{2k} ^{2k+1} e^{-x} -\int _{2k+1} ^{2k+2} e^{-x}] dx$.
Evaluate the integrals then sum the resulting geometric series.